# MongoDB $lookup or $graphLookup aggregation recursively and stop the lookup with a condition

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am trying to use the $lookup or the graphLookup aggregation to search for some related docs in the same collection, but I want to stop the lookup once a condition is met.
Below is an example of what I want to do:

example of documents in collection:

```json
{
    "_id":1,
    "name":"Bob",
    "idNumber":"111111-1",
    "conditionField": true,
    "enabled": false
},
{
    "_id":2,
    "name":"Bob",
    "idNumber":"111111-1",
    "conditionField": false,
    "enabled": false
},
{
    "_id":3,
    "name":"Bob",
    "idNumber":"111111-1",
    "conditionField": true,
    "enabled": false
},
{
    "_id":4,
    "name":"Bob",
    "idNumber":"111111-1",
    "conditionField": true,
    "enabled": false
},
{
    "_id":5,
    "name":"Bob",
    "idNumber":"111111-1",
    "conditionField": true,
    "enabled": true
}
```

I want to query the single document where the `enabled` field is `true`, then lookup in ascending order, all the other documents where the `enabled` is `false`, `name` and `idNumber`fields match the enabled document. But I want to stop the lookup once it finds a document where the `conditionField`is equal to `false` and ignore the rest.

this is the query that I have right now:

```json
[
  {
    '$match': {
      'enabled': true
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'collection', 
      'let': {
        'name': '$name', 
        'idNumber': '$idNumber'
      }, 
      'pipeline': [
        {
          '$match': {
            '$expr': {
              '$and': [
                {'$eq': ['$name', '$$name']}, 
                {'$eq': ['$idNumber', '$$idNumber'] }, 
                {'$eq': ['$enabled', false]}
              ]
            }
          }
        }, 
        {'$sort': {'_id': -1} }
      ], 
      'as': 'relatedDocs'
    }
  }
]
```

This query return returns all the related documents like this:

```json
{
    "_id":5,
    "name":"Bob",
    "idNumber":"111111-1",
    "conditionField": true,
    "enabled": true,
    "relatedDocs":[
      {
        "_id":4,
        "name":"Bob",
        "idNumber":"111111-1",
        "conditionField": true,
        "enabled": false
      },
      {
        "_id":3,
        "name":"Bob",
        "idNumber":"111111-1",
        "conditionField": true,
        "enabled": false
       },
       {
        "_id":2,
        "name":"Bob",
        "idNumber":"111111-1",
        "conditionField": false,
        "enabled": false
       },
       {
        "_id":1,
        "name":"Bob",
        "idNumber":"111111-1",
        "conditionField": true,
        "enabled": false
       }
    ]

}
```

But what I really want is to stop the lookup once it finds a documents where "conditionField" is equal to "false" and ignore the rests. So the result I am looking for is this:

```json
{
    "_id":5,
    "name":"Bob",
    "idNumber":"111111-1",
    "conditionField": true,
    "enabled": true,
    "relatedDocs":[
      {
        "_id":4,
        "name":"Bob",
        "idNumber":"111111-1",
        "conditionField": true,
        "enabled": false
      },
      {
        "_id":3,
        "name":"Bob",
        "idNumber":"111111-1",
        "conditionField": true,
        "enabled": false
       }
    ]

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new stage after your query,

- `$reduce` to iterate loop of `relatedDocs` array, check condition if `conditionField` is true and `status` in initial value is `true`, then return concat arrays using `$concatArrays`, otherwise return false

```
  {
    $addFields: {
      relatedDocs: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$relatedDocs",
          initialValue: { result: [], status: true },
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {
                $and: [
                  { $eq: ["$$this.conditionField", true] },
                  { $eq: ["$$value.status", true] }
                ]
              },
              {
                result: { $concatArrays: ["$$value.result", ["$$this"]] },
                status: "$$value.status"
              },
              {
                result: "$$value.result",
                status: false
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ihiPhbYYjUP)